# Error response from daemon: network ehmnzctsw789v3kjher5rsil6 not found Error: failed to start containers: mfa-bionix-db-mongo-windows

Tags: docker

Am trying to run the command Docker container Start (service/project), i get the error - **Error response from daemon: network ehmnzctsw789v3kjher5rsil6 not found
Error: failed to start containers: mfa-bionix-db-mongo-windows**

unable to figure out what is going on here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide additional data? `Dockerfile`, `command` you are using to setup and start docker image and `full error`.

Comment: The command is - Docker Container Start mfa-bionix-db-mongo-windows (This is a service) when i execute this command in power shell i get the error -  Error response from daemon: network ehmnzctsw789v3kjher5rsil6 not found Error: failed to start containers: mfa-bionix-db-mongo-windows

Comment: Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container mfa-bionix-es-mongo-windows: network yimj1vgf5c4umruvw3qqmn5h2 not found (network not found), what does this mean?